# UIView add gesture recognizer inside UITableViewController static cells

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using static table view cells inside a UITableViewController. What I've done is create a outlet of a view and add gesture recognizer.

```
let tap = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hello))
myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

The function is as follow.

```
@objc func hello(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("hello")
}
```

But after I tapping the myView which is a UIView. Nothing's printed.

Comment: `UITapGestureRecognizer` tried this instead?
also `myView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: @MumtazHussain I've tried adding that. But not working

Comment: do you have any views on top of myView? if so then you need to pass the clicks to the parent myView with `gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch`

Comment: there's no views on top of the views. It's working now buy changing the UIView to UIControl and using IBAction with touchup inside.

Comment: You should set cell selection none. Because tableview has its own didselect method. Either you use didselect of tableview or close cell selection style and use your custom gesture recognizer :)